# Condicional respecto a un campo en la vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Estoy haciendo un mantenimiento en MVC para una tabla empleados. He hecho un grid que muestra la lista de empleados, y le agregue botones para editar y borrar en cada registro, pero quiero que envés de decir borrar diga "Dar de Alta" o "Dar de baja" dependiendo del campo estado de la tabla empleados.
Este es el código de la vista:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppProfileDAL.v_employee>
@using GridMvc.Html

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="right-side">

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "v_employee")" class="btn btn-primary active">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nuevo
    </a>
</p>



@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(
columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.nombres).Titled("Name");
    columns.Add(c => c.apellidos).Titled("Last Name");
    columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", "v_employee", new { Id = o.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());
    if () { //Aquí esta el problema
        columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Down", "Delete", "v_employee", new { Id = o.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());
    }
    else
    {
        columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Up", "Delete", "v_employee", new { Id = o.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());
    }

    columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Imprimir", "Print", "v_employee", new { Id = o.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());

}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

Saben alguna forma de leer el campo estado de la tabla y ponerlo en la condicional del if?

Gracias!

Comment: Hi, Francisco This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: porque defines de esta forma columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false)  una columna ?

Comment: Para agregar links que digan "Editar", "Borrar", "Imprimir" en cada fila y se vea Nombre|Apellid|Editar|Borrar|Imprimir

Answer (score 1):

Las columnas no pueden ser condicionales, o la muestras o no, pero aplica a toda la tabla. Lo que puedes variar es el contenido de las celdas de cada row  para esa columna.

Recomendaría que definas una unica columna y el condicional de la accion lo defines en el `format`

```
columns.Add("Titulo Columna", format: (item) =>
        {
            if (condicion)
            {
                return Html.Raw(Html.ActionLink("Up", "Delete", "v_employee", new { Id = item.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());
            }
            else
            {
                return Html.Raw(Html.ActionLink("Down", "Delete", "v_employee", new { Id = item.user_id}, null).ToHtmlString());
            }
        })
```

De esta forma muestras un link u otro pero bajo la misma columna.